# How does Python import work in this example?

Tags: python, import, scipy, python-import

I get an error if I do the following:

```
import scipy as sp
sp.sparse.identity(10)
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'sparse'
```

From this, I infer that I need to explicitly import `scipy.sparse`. However, if I instead "go too far" and import `scipy.sparse.linalg`, I get no error:

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sla
import scipy as sp
sp.sparse.identity(10)
```

This is rather unintuitive to me. What happened? Why does it work like this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, since `scipy` is very large, it doesn't import all the modules directly. You can only only import the ones you require directly. There are a lot more packages which do this. They are generally very large.

As it's a separate sub-package, once you import it, it's attributes are available to you by using the regular scipy.module.attribute

Hope you understood :)

Comment: Yes but I never imported the `scipy.sparse` module. I only imported the `scipy.sparse.linalg` module, which is why I am confused.

Comment: I do not believe this is correct, as you can import the sparse package directly. ```from scipy import sparse```

Comment: You can import it like `from scipy import sparse`. You just cannot do `import scipy` and then use a submodule of scipy like `scipy.sparse`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is because of a broken install as stated in the closed issue of github. I think python is confusing between two different modules named the same.

Here is the link to the issue:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/13678

Comment: Not sure about this... the examples I give are completely stand alone and I do not use scikit-learn?

Comment: @Grayscale A similar example is given in the issue where the user tries importing sparse but is not able to. I have the same issue as well and cannot import Sparse the way you have shown but can import it this way ```from scipy import sparse```